# How can I change a CSS class automatically according to time?

Tags: javascript

I am building a weather app where I have a day mode and a night mode. The time changes according to the time the city the user searches. I tried to use this code to switch between the different CSS of the night mode and the day mode

```
function getMode(response) {
  let today = response.data.dt;
  let timezone = response.data.timezone;
  let difference = today + timezone - 3600;
  let hours = timeConverter2(difference);
  let mode = document.getElementById("app");
  if (hours > 17 || hours < 6) {
    mode.classList.add("darkmode").remove("lightmode");
  }
  if (hours < 17 || hours > 6) {
    mode.classList.add("lightmode").remove("darkmode");
  }
}
```

where "app" is where I put the class "lightmode" in the HTML file like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="app" class="lightmode">
```

(it's wrapping my whole code).

The problem is it changed to dark mode when my current time was supposed to change but when I search for a city where it's still day time it doesn't change back to light mode, despite the hours variable being an API response from the local time.

Changing the CSS from JavaScript would be a nightmare since there are many, many classes to change with a lot of parameters.

Any suggestions or mistakes I'm not seeing?

I'm adding a minimal reproducible example with HTML, CSS, and Javascript here:

```js
function search(city) {
  let apiKey = "fe5b1ec1d3199b1c1bb7ae3cbda78fc9";
  let url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&appid=${apiKey}`;
  axios.get(url).then(currentCity);
  axios.get(url).then(todayDate);
  axios.get(url).then(todayTime);
  axios.get(url).then(getMode);
}

function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let input = document.querySelector("#keyword");
  search(input.value);
}

let form = document.querySelector("form");
form.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);

search("Lisbon,pt");

function currentCity(response) {
  let city = document.querySelector(".current-city");
  let place = response.data.name;
  city.innerHTML = `${place}`;
}

function todayDate(response) {
  let today = response.data.dt;
  let timezone = response.data.timezone;
  let difference = today + timezone - 3600;
  let date = document.querySelector(".date");
  date.innerHTML = timeConverter(difference);
}

function todayTime(response) {
  let time = response.data.dt;
  let timezone = response.data.timezone;
  let difference = time + timezone - 3600;
  let timeToday = document.querySelector(".time");
  timeToday.innerHTML = timeConverter4(difference);
}

function timeConverter(epoch) {
  let a = new Date(epoch * 1000);
  let months = [
    "Jan",
    "Feb",
    "Mar",
    "Apr",
    "May",
    "Jun",
    "Jul",
    "Aug",
    "Sep",
    "Oct",
    "Nov",
    "Dec"
  ];
  let month = months[a.getMonth()];
  let date = a.getDate();
  let time = `${month} ${date}`;
  return time;
}

function timeConverter2(epoch) {
  let a = new Date(epoch * 1000);
  let hour = a.getHours();
  let time = `${hour}`;
  return time;
}

function timeConverter4(epoch) {
  let a = new Date(epoch * 1000);
  let hour = a.getHours();
  let minutes = a.getMinutes();
  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = `0${minutes}`;
  }
  let time = `${hour}:${minutes}`;
  return time;
}

function getMode(response) {
  let today = response.data.dt;
  let timezone = response.data.timezone;
  let difference = today + timezone - 3600;
  let hours = timeConverter2(difference);
  let mode = document.getElementById("app");
  if (hours > 20 || hours < 6) {
    mode.classList.add("darkmode").remove("lightmode");
  } else {
    mode.classList.add("lightmode").remove("darkmode");
  }
}
```

```css
.lightmode h1 {
  font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
  text-align: right;
  color: #06384d;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.lightmode {
  font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #a1c4fd 0%, #c2e9fb 100%);
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border-color: #096386;
}

#app {
  margin: 10px 400px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.element {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 100px;
  position: relative;
  right: 10px;
}

.lightmode .current {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  top: 5px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #06384d;
}

.lightmode .current-city {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #06384d;
}

.lightmode .date {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #06384d;
}

.lightmode .time {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #06384d;
}

.darkmode h1 {
  font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
  text-align: right;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.darkmode {
  font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #30cfd0 0%, #330867 100%);
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border-color: #096386;
}

.darkmode .current {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  top: 5px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
}

.darkmode .current-city {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
}

.darkmode .date {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
}

.darkmode .time {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app" class="lightmode">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>WeatherWatch</h1>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <form>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="keyword" placeholder="Search city..." aria-label="Input city" aria-describedby="button-addon2" autocomplete="off" />
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <submit class="btn btn-outline-secondary search-btn" type="button" id="button-addon2">
            Search
          </submit>
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="element">
        </div>
        <span class="current"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <span class="current-city">Lisbon</span>
        <p class="date"></p>
        <p class="time"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: How do you call `getMode()`? I assume you invoke it every time you search for a different city? And upon searching, is `hours` getting updated correctly?

Comment: I call it using axios, I have a search(city) function that has the API url inside and I call it using axios.get(url).then(getMode).

Comment: Every time the city gets searched, hours gets updated.

Comment: `get_mode` looks like it should do what you want, so the problem is elsewhere.  You need to show how you're invoking `get_mode`.  (In other words, please provide a [mcve])

Comment: can you tell me what the `hours` variable is?

Comment: `hours` is a converted unix timestamp into actual hours (in 24h)

Comment: If you `console.log(hours)`, is the value what you expect in the cases that are failing?

Comment: Yep, the values are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the interest of someone with a similar problem, I simply changed the order of the code in this way:

```
if (hours > 17) {
    mode.classList.add("darkmode").remove("lightmode");
  }
  if (hours < 6) {
    mode.classList.add("darkmode").remove("lightmode");
  } else {
    mode.classList.remove("darkmode").add("lightmode");
  }
}
```

and have the last line

```
mode.classList.remove("darkmode").add("lightmode");
```

instead of

```
mode.classList.add("lightmode").remove("darkmode");
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is here:

```
if (hours > 17 || hours < 6) {
  mode.classList.add("darkmode").remove("lightmode");
}
if (hours < 17 || hours > 6) {
  mode.classList.add("lightmode").remove("darkmode");
}
```

Lets take 3am as example, both loops satisfy the condition. So it should be this:

```
if (hours > 17 || hours < 6) {
  mode.classList.add("darkmode").remove("lightmode");
}
else {
  mode.classList.add("lightmode").remove("darkmode");
}
```

You should also check for edge cases:

```
if (hours >= 6 && hours <= 17) {
  mode.classList.add("lightmode").remove("darkmode");
}
else {
  mode.classList.add("darkmode").remove("lightmode");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I had it like this before, the problem remains!

Comment: @mfs did you try the option with && or just the || options?

Comment: Just the ||... a number can't be simultaneously bigger than 17 and smaller than 6, right?

Comment: @mfs: like this = like which one? `hours < 17 || hours > 6` is always true.

Comment: Any more debugging will need a minimal reproducible example I'm afraid.

Comment: Sorry I am kind of new to this, what should go into the mre?

Comment: I added minimal code to reproduce the problem I'm experiencing, the problem is reproducible here. The default city "Lisbon" produces darkmode, if you type "Los Angeles" it doesn't change to lightmode like it should.